# Use of yield with a dict comprehension

Tags: python, generator, yield

As a contrived example:

```
myset = set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
mydict = {item: (yield ''.join([item, 's'])) for item in myset}
```

and `list(mydict)` gives:

```
['as', 'cs', 'bs', 'ds', {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None}]
```

What happens here? What does `yield` do? And is this behavior consistent no matter what expression follows `yield`?

Note: I know that doing `mydict = {item: ''.join([item, 's']) for item in myset}` would give the dictionary `{'a': 'as', 'b': 'bs', 'c': 'cs', 'd': 'ds'}`, which seems to be what I am trying to do here.

Comment: Wow.  I would've lost good money betting that was a SyntaxError.

Comment: @DSM -- Me too.  I'm guessing that the dict comprehension is implemented as a wrapper around generator expressions.  (after all, `{k:v for k,v in ...}` is equivalent to `dict((k,v) for k,v in ...)`

Comment: I think the moral of the story is:  "Don't try this at home" ;-).  But very interesting question (+1).

Comment: In python3 the `list(mydict)` is just `['as', 'cs', 'bs', 'ds']`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, what does `yield` return? The answer in this case is `None`, because `yield` returns the parameter passed to `next()`, which is nothing in this case (`list` doesn't pass anything to `next`).

Now here's your answer:

```
>>> myset = set(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> mydict = {item: (yield ''.join([item, 's'])) for item in myset}
>>> mydict
<generator object <dictcomp> at 0x0222BB20>
```

The dict comprehension is turned into a generator, because you used `yield` in a function body context! This means that the whole thing isn't evaluated until it's passed into `list`.

So here's what happens:

1. `list` calls `next(mydict)`.
2. Yield returns `''.join([item, 's'])` to `list` and freezes the comprehension.
3. `list` calls `next(mydict)`.
4. The comprehension resumes and assigns the result of `yield` (`None`) to `item` in the dictionary and starts a new comprehension iteration.
5. Go back to 1.

And at last the actual generator object returns the temporary in the body, which was the `dict`. Why this happens is unknown to me, and it's probably not documented behaviour either.

Answer (score 4):

I think that `yield` is turning your nice dictionary comprehension into a generator expression.  So, when you're iterating over the generator, yield is "yielding" the elements that look `as`, `bs` ..., but the statement `yield ...` returns `None`.  So, at the end of the day, you get a dictionary looking like `{'a': None, 'b': None, ...}`.

The part that confuses me is why the dictionary is actually yielded at the end.  I'm guessing that this behavior is actually not well defined by the standard, but I could be wrong about that.

Interestingly enough, if you try this with a list comprehension, python complains:

```
>>> a = [(yield i) for i in myset]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function
```

But it's [Ok in a generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324096/attempting-to-understand-yield-as-an-expression) (apparently).

Comment: FWIW pypy doesn't give the dictionary: `list(mydict)` produces `['as', 'cs', 'bs', 'ds']`, which if you'd told me that the expression was valid would be what I'd've guessed it would have returned.

Comment: So either pypy has it wrong, or it isn't defined behavior (my money's on the second).

Comment: @DSM -- What does `pypy` return for `dict( (item,(yield (item+'s'))) for item in 'abdc')`?

Comment: `{'a': None, 'c': None, 'b': None, 'd': None}`.

Comment: @DSM -- Thanks.  Not sure where I was going with that thought, but, it's interesting (and not surprising) that pypy and Cpython agree on that one.

Answer (score 2):

I find! ^_^

In normal life, expression

```
print {item: (yield ''.join([item, 's'])) for item in myset}
```

evaluate like this:

```
def d(myset):
    result = {}
    for item in myset:
        result[item] = (''.join([item, 's']))
    yield result

print d(myset).next()
```

Why `yield result` instead `return result`? I think it is necessary to support nested list comprehensions* like this:

```
print {i: f.lower() for i in nums for f in fruit}  # yes, it's works
```

So, would look like this code?

```
def d(myset):
    result = {}
    for item in myset:
        result[item] = (yield ''.join([item, 's']))
    yield result
```

and

```
>>> print list(d(myset))
['as', 'cs', 'bs', 'ds', {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None}]
```

First will be returned all values of `''.join([item, 's'])` and the last will be returned dict `result`. Value of `yield` expression is `None`, so values in the `result` is `None` too.

* More correct interpretation of evaluate nested list comprehensions:

```
print {i: f.lower() for i in nums for f in fruit}

# eval like this:

result = {}
for i, f in product(nums, fruit): # product from itertools
    key, value = (i, f.lower())
    result[key] = value
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code has to execute similarity of this:

```
def d(myset):
    for item in myset:
        yield item, (yield ''.join([item, 's']))

d(myset)
```

Firstly, evaluated `yield ''.join([item, 's']` (and return 'as', 'cs', etc.). Value of yield expression is None, because is sent back to the generator. And then eval `yield item, None`, that return tuples ('a', None), ('b', None).

So, I have:

```
>>> list(d(myset))
['as', ('a', None), 'cs', ('c', None), 'bs', ('b', None), 'ds', ('d', None)]
```

What happens next, I do not understand.