# (list|set|dict) comprehension containing a yield expression does not return a (list|set|dict)

Tags: python, generator

### Python 3.3

I've constructed this *slightly* cryptic piece of python 3.3:

```
>>> [(yield from (i, i + 1, i)) for i in range(5)]
<generator object <listcomp> at 0x0000008666D96900>
>>> list(_)
[0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4]
```

If I use a generator comprehension inside a list constructor, I get a different result:

```
>>> list((yield from (i, i + 1, i)) for i in range(5))
[0, 1, 0, None, 1, 2, 1, None, 2, 3, 2, None, 3, 4, 3, None, 4, 5, 4, None]
```

Why isn't the list comprehension returning a list?

### Python 2.7

I can get a similarly odd effect in python 2 (using a set comprehension, because list comprehensions have odd scope):

```
>>> {(yield i) for i in range(5)}
<generator object <setcomp> at 0x0000000004A06120>
>>> list(_)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, {None}]
```

And when using a generator comprehension:

```
>>> list((yield i) for i in range(5))
[0, None, 1, None, 2, None, 3, None, 4, None]
```

Where'd that `{None}` come from?

Comment: Inspired by the atrocity in [How does this lambda/yield/generator comprehension work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955948/how-does-this-lambda-yield-generator-comprehension-work)

Comment: You've produced a generator that generates a generator.

Comment: [This seems related](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-ideas/JOFw5Al-kEM) but I don't grok it enough to explain it myself, yet.

Comment: Isn't yield supposed to produce a generator, i.e. not a collection, but a structure capable of generating a collection?

Comment: It seems to me that it has something to do with the internals of whether python is building a function (set comp or, in python 3, any comp), or an object (list comp in python 2).

Comment: IOW since it's a function, the `yield` expression makes it a generator. In Python 2 it's not a function, so…you just can't use `yield` at all in a listcomp.

Comment: Good thing that using `yield` here isn't really necessary.  The straight forward `[ j for i in range(5) for j in (i, i+1, i) ]` works as expected.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358063/use-of-yield-with-a-dict-comprehension).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List (set, dict) comprehensions translate to a different code structure from generator expressions.  Let's look at a set comprehension:

```
def f():
    return {i for i in range(10)}

dis.dis(f.__code__.co_consts[1])
  2           0 BUILD_SET                0
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                12 (to 21)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
             12 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             15 SET_ADD                  2
             18 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   21 RETURN_VALUE
```

Compare to the equivalent generator expression:

```
def g():
    return (i for i in range(10))

dis.dis(g.__code__.co_consts[1])
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    3 FOR_ITER                11 (to 17)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             12 YIELD_VALUE         
             13 POP_TOP             
             14 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

You'll notice that where the generator expression has a `yield`, the set comprehension stores a value directly into the set it is building.

This means that if you add a `yield` expression into the body of a generator expression, it is treated indistinguishably from the `yield` that the language constructs for the generator body; as a result, you get two (or more) values per iteration.

However, if you add a `yield` to a list (set, dict) comprehension then the comprehension is transformed from a function building a list (set, dict) into a generator that executes the `yield` statements then returns the constructed list (set, dict).  The `{None}` in the set comprehension result is the set built from each of the `None`s that the `yield` expressions evaluate to.

---

Finally, why does Python 3.3 not produce a `{None}`? (Note that previous versions of Python 3 do.)  It's because of [PEP 380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) (a.k.a. `yield from` support).  Prior to Python 3.3, a `return` in a generator is a `SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator`; our `yield`ing comprehensions are therefore exploiting undefined behaviour, but the actual result of the `RETURN_VALUE` opcode is to just generate another (final) value from the generator.  In Python 3.3, `return value` is explicitly supported; a `RETURN_VALUE` opcode results in a `StopIteration` being raised, which has the effect of stopping the generator without producing a final value.

Comment: Why does the set `{None}` end up being yielded, when the python 3 list `[None] * 5` does not?

Comment: Actually, running the same code in python3 does _not_ yield a `{None}`

Comment: @Eric it's because of PEP 380 (`yield from`).  I'll add an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Using [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-ideas/JOFw5Al-kEM) as a reference:

### Python 3 explanation

This:

```
values = [(yield from (i, i + 1, i)) for i in range(5)]
```

Translates to the following in Python 3.x:

```
def _tmpfunc(): 
    _tmp = [] 
    for x in range(5): 
        _tmp.append(yield from (i, i + 1, i)) 
    return _tmp 
values = _tmpfunc()
```

Which results in `values` containing a generator

That generator will then yield from each `(i, i + 1, i)`, until finally reaching the return statement. In python 3, this will `throw StopIteration(_tmp)` - however, this exception is ignored by the `list` constructor.

---

On the other hand, this:

```
list((yield from (i, i + 1, i)) for i in range(5))
```

Translates to the following in Python 3.x:

```
def _tmpfunc():
    for x in range(5): 
        yield (yield from (i, i + 1, i))

values = list(_tmpfunc())
```

This time, every time the `yield from` completes, it evaluates to `None`, which is then `yield`ed amidst the other values.

Comment: Yeah.  I'd say using `yield` in this place simply breaks the concept; the compiler should reject it as it will never lead to useful results.  (But I'd be happy to be corrected.)

Comment: Is the `_tmp` variable created and returned in the `_tmpfunc()`?  Or maybe it is created outside, passed to the function, and changed in-place, to that no `return` is even necessary?

Comment: @Alfe: Ah, I believe that may be the distinction between python 2 and 3 - 3 is definitely doing a return, because there's a `StopIteration`