# Passing value to yield using send

Tags: python, python-2.7, yield

When i was googling for python `yield` i found something interesting and I never knew before i.e we can pass value to yield to change the next() value. I hope some of the new pythonist might now aware of this and I am not sure how it works too. So, If any body could explain how it works and how the behavior changes when i send a new index to yield using `send()`.

Here is my snippets :

```
def print_me (count):
    i = 0
    while i < count:
        val = (yield i)
        if val is not None:
            i = val
        else:
            i += 1

gen = print_me(10)

for i in gen:
   if i == 5:
       gen.send(8)
   else:
       print i
```

Here is my output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
9
```

Comment: What is your question?  What part of the behavior do you not understand?

Comment: When i send a new index, how the yield point to new index. Basically I am confusing `yield` is using some kind of linked list or ?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by "how yield point to new index".  When you use `send`, the value you send becomes the value of the `yield` expression.  How you use that in the generator is up to you.

Comment: This "enhanced" generator syntax was added in python 2.5 and is used to build coroutines.  [read more in the PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/)

Comment: Here's some interesting related information: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12324096/748858

Answer (score 4):

Your test code is pretty instructive actually.  What happens in a generator function like this is that whenever you call `next` on the generator, code gets executed until it hits a `yield` statement.  The value is yielded and then execution in the generator "pauses".  If you [`.send`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.send) some data to the generator, that value is *returned* from `yield`.  If you don't `.send` anything, `yield` returns `None`.

So in your code, when you `.send(8)`, then it sets `val = 8` inside your generator  (`val = yield i`).  since `val is not None`, `i` is set to `8`.  `.send` actually executes until the next yield statement (returning that value -- `8`).  Then things resume as normal (the next number to be yielded is `9`).

Comment: An important thing to note is that `send` advances the generator (i.e., runs it until the next `yield` and gives you the next value).  This sometimes confuses people.

Comment: @BrenBarn -- Thanks,  That's true (I always need to look that up).  I've clarified the answer a bit.

Comment: Thank you @BrenBarn and mgilson. I think now i got it.

Comment: Is there any use case for this advancing `yield` ? i din't see anything.

Comment: @yopy -- coroutines.  I've not used them myself, so I can't really give you a good use-case.  Take a look at the coroutines and info in the PEP posted by roippi.